# Need to align top and wrap text while using FPDF?

Tags: php, sql, fpdf

Hi i am using fpdf to generate pdf automatically to read data from sql >since most of the content pulled from db it a paragraph of around 300words ..it not being wrapped by the columns i made in fpdf..it just goes as a single line..Is there any way to wrap the text with in the column .output image is attached at the end of the post..One more questain,how can i send this pdf to email automatically

```
   <?php

require('fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database
$link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxxxx.co.uk', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new FPDF();

//Open file
$pdf->Open();

//Disable automatic page break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage();

//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 25;

//print column titles for the actual page
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(5);
/*$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'CODE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'NAME', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'R', 1);*/

$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;


mysql_select_db("web39-sdasdasd", $link);
$q = "SELECT qr_topics,start_of,differential_dia,things_not,investigations,risks FROM qr_table";
$result = mysql_query ($q, $link);

//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 80;
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, '  ', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Starting off', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Differential diagnosis', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Not to miss', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Investigations', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Risks', 1, 0, 'L', 1);

$y_axis =(35);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


    $cad = $row['qr_topics'];
    $pad = $row['start_of'];
    $nad = $row['differential_dia'];
    $vad = $row['things_not'];
    $sad = $row['investigations'];
    $tad = $row['risks'];

    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$cad,1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$pad,1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$nad,1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$vad,1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$sad,1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(33,80,$tad,1,0,'L',1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = $i + 1;
}

mysql_close($link);

//Send file
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

The output is shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row_height = 80;
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, '  ', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Starting off', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Differential diagnosis', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Not to miss', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Investigations', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(33, 6, 'Risks', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
```

Change from L to T or R

Comment: According to the documentation and my own testing, 'T' only relates to adding a border to the top. http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm